# How add this view dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add some view **dynamically.**

```
LinearLayout mDescriptionLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.descriptionLayout); 

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.bonus_info_item, null,false);
TextView counter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.counter);
TextView descriptionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
String [] s = {"","A","B", "C","D"};

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    counter.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    descriptionText.setText(s[i]);
    mDescriptionLayout.addView(view);
}
```

This is my `main.xml` and I want add this inflated view in `LinearLayout`(`@id/descriptionLayout`)

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/days"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/descriptionLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bonusCardTitleText"
                android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I don't understand what is the problem in here that I can't add view **dynamically** and I always got this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3339)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3155)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)
```

Comment: When you create your layout in xml, the layouts are already being created. You don't have to add them again, this will cause error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says,

`The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

you are trying to add a child `View` to a parent and the child already has a parent( after the first iteration of your `for loop`). Either declaring and initializing the `View` inside the `for loop` or calling `remove()` each time should fix it. I'm not sure if you are trying to add this `layout` multiple times like that but if so then you can try

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.bonus_info_item, null,false);
    TextView counter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.counter);
    TextView descriptionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
    counter.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    descriptionText.setText(s[i]);
    mDescriptionLayout.addView(view);
}
```

Another way would be to call `mDescriptionLayout.removeView(view);` but I don't think you want to do this in your situation. Initializing a new `View` with each iteration through the `loop` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same `TextView` object more than once to the `LinearLayout`. You need to create a new instance of `TextView` for each item.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.bonus_info_item, null,false);
    TextView counter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.counter);
    TextView descriptionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
    counter.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    descriptionText.setText(s[i]);
    mDescriptionLayout.addView(view);
}
```